# How (is it possible) to make available an iPhone's file by url?

Tags: ios, file, url, hyperlink, share

I am coding for iOs. I would like to interact with a webservices platform for treatment of a captured image. Unfortunately, it asks me an URL of a picture and not a picture, here's my question:

Can we make available a picture (a file) from an iPhone by associating it with a public URL? Perhaps through the IP of the iPhone? (the iPhone would be a server...)

I looked for using of icloud but not very successful. I may use dropBox API, in this case i would use the public folder which can generate public URL...

Nicolas (sorry for my english).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. You should upload it to a server, store it there and use the url on that server.